# Can I change the future tense into the past tense?

Tags: tense, reported-speech

Can I change the future tense into the past tense when I change the direct speech into the indirect speech?

“I will open the door”

1. I said I would open the door.
2. I said I opened the door.

The door was already opened, so doesn’t it matter if I say I said I opened the door like the present tense becomes the past tense?

Answer (score 3):

When changing direct speech to reported speech, we must not change the meaning. If someone says "I will open the door", using the future tense in their speech, at that time that person has not yet opened the door, and is uttering a prediction or intention. In reported speech, you can only write "He said that he would open the door". It does not matter what happened after the person spoke the words.

[Tense changes when using reported speech](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/tense-changes-when-using-reported-speech/)